# Divs don't change position on small resolution when changing float

Tags: html, css

I am making my site responsive and the dekstop version has a layout like this:

```
|    HEADER    |
<br>
| TEXT | IMAGE |
<br>
| IMAGE | TEXT |
<br>
| TEXT | IMAGE |
```

**What I want is this:** 
When on phone resolution I made a media query so that all the images float left, and the text floats right. like this:

```
|    HEADER    |<br>

|     IMAGE    |<br>
|     TEXT     |<br><br>
|     IMAGE    |<br>
|     TEXT     |<br><br>
|     IMAGE    |<br>
|     TEXT     |
```

**What it actually does:** 
However, it it sticks to the layout of the html, and when I am on dekstop resolution it does change the position of the images to the left and the text to the right, but when on phone resolution it stays to the origional layout and it messes it up like this :

```
|    HEADER    |
<br>
| TEXT |<br> IMAGE |
<br>
| IMAGE |<br> TEXT |
<br>
| TEXT |<br> IMAGE |
```

**html/php code** (left out the php & content)

```
<div class="productcol">

        <div class="productimg"> 

        </div>


        <div class="producteentweede">

            <div class="producttext">


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="productcol">

        <div class="producteentweede">

            <div class="producttext">


            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="productimg"> 

        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
        .productcol{
        width:100%;
        margin-left:0;
    }

    .producteentweede{
        width:50%;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
    }

    .productimg{
        width:50%;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        height:30em;
    }


@media all and (max-width: 620px) {

    .producteentweede{
        float:right!important;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }

    .productimg{
        float:left!important;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:22em;
    }
}
```

Comment: *html/php code (left out the php & content)* -- so PHP isn't the matter. So there's no need for PHP tag.

Comment: The question is not clear at all, sorry. There are no images in the markup or in the CSS. Can you make a jsfiddle or something that demonstrates the issue? I mean, I made one ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xufz3cu8/)), but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: My apologies, I will make a jsfiddle now and update you soon

Comment: Also, it might help if you could make a screenshot that would show what effect you're after; the formatting here in the question editor doesn't really help clarify things.

Comment: This is what my code does now:
https://jsfiddle.net/xufz3cu8/8/
The fullscreen layout is fine, but when you resize it after a while 2 images stick to eachother. This is obvious because that's how the HTML is set up; however the float on the media queries should change their position.

This is what I need it to look:
https://jsfiddle.net/xufz3cu8/9/
(non responsive version, just changed the layout of html).

This NEEDS to be done in css.

Comment: @tehchriis I think it's better modifying the HTML structure first (to properly represent the data) and then use CSS to change the display/layout. Have a look at my code below and the JSFiddle, should make your page a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the HTML structure first, and then use CSS to adjust the layout for the "full-size" layout and the "mobile" layout. You can assign classes to the image/text elements to tell them if they should move to the right or the left:

```
<div class="productcol">
    <div class="producteentweede right">
        <div class="producttext">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productimg left">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="productcol">
    <div class="producteentweede left">
        <div class="producttext">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productimg right">

    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can add some CSS to achieve this for the "full-size" layout. The "mobile" layout should just work because the HTML structure has been fixed up.

```
.producteentweede, .productimg{
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    height:10em;
    float:left;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle for the result: https://jsfiddle.net/mqszbej6/

Comment: No problem, hope it has helped! :)